# Откуда взялось слово "шавка"?

Tags: этимология

У меня глупый вопрос, но все-таки интересно: откуда взялось слово "шавка" для обозначения мелких склочных собачонок? Это кличка какой-то конкретной собаки, ставшая нарицательной, или это слово что-то значит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По Фасмеру, ближайшая этимология слова ШАВКА: (Крылов), шавкать "тявкать, шамкать", укр. шавкати "чавкать", блр. шавкаць "говорить невнятно". Это звукоподражательное слово.

Answer (score 1):

В XIX веке считали иначе: "Шафка или шавка — небольшая порода собак с пушистым хвостом и высокой шерстью".
[Новейший полный словотолкователь и объяснитель 150000 иностранных слов, вошедших в русский язык с приведением корней и исследований о происхождении их, 1886 г.](https://www.prlib.ru/node/351578/source)

Comment: Дмитрий, я подправила Ваш ответ и внесла ссылку (надеюсь, Вы не против). P. S. Для тех, кто захочет посмотреть: выбрать "чтение", в поле набрать "шафка" или "шавка" (масштаб можно увеличить).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо за ссылку. Дмитрий, а в чём именно "считали иначе"? Я не вижу противоречия. Замечу заодно, что когда-то в ходу была версия (Горяев, конец XIX в.), что слово "шафка" заимствовано с немецкого Schaferhund. Потом эта версия была признана ошибочной.

Answer (score 0):

в древнеиндийском (Санскрите) это слово означало "щенята" или вообще "дети животных" (शावक - "шавака"). видимо, индоевропейский артефакт. у нас таких очень много, особенно в диалектах - архаичный язык русский.